# Limiting which OS X versions see an app in the OS X App Store

Tags: macos, app-store

How do I populate metadata that tells the App Store which versions of OS X is the minimum required for my app? I can't seem to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's *OS Deployment Target* build setting is used by Xcode to set the info.plist *Minimum System Version* (`LSMinimumSystemVersion`) key. You can set the deployment target directly in the *General* tab in the project info.

HTH

Comment: Yes, so key point: it's an attribute of the application rather than something you supply separately for the listing, which I think follows the natural logic.